# Is it possible to have a meaningful error in LLVM stack dump?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm getting a "stack dump" while trying to run a program that uses LLVM API for generating code:

```
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: ./llvm-playground
1.  Running pass 'Simplify the CFG' on function '@foo'
0  libLLVM.dylib            0x000000010397c1e5 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 40
1  libLLVM.dylib            0x000000010397c5e8 SignalHandler(int) + 180
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff7d689b5d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 2190959808
...
25 llvm-playground          0x000000010380591d main + 893
26 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff7d49e3d5 start + 1
27 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000001 start + 2192972845
[1]    14917 segmentation fault  ./llvm-playground
```

The generated IR looks like this:

```
; ModuleID = 'MyModule'
source_filename = "MyModule"

define i32 @foo(i32 %arg1) #0 {
entry:
  %malloccall = tail call i8* @malloc(i64 8)
  %0 = bitcast i8* %malloccall to i32*
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds i32, i32* %0, i32 1
  store i32 5, i32* %1
}

declare noalias i8* @malloc(i32*)

attributes #0 = { "target-cpu"="skylake" }
```

When compiling the same IR code with `llc` the problem can be spotted right away (missing return statement):

```
error: expected instruction opcode
}
```

Is it possible to have the same error message in stack dumps LLVM produces?

Comment: Run `Verifier` pass after generating your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the missing piece of code that adds the needed error message:

```cpp
std::string ModuleBuilder::GetIR() const {
  std::string module_str;
  llvm::raw_string_ostream ostream{module_str};
  module_->print(ostream, nullptr, false);
  return module_str;
}

void ModuleBuilder::Verify() const {
  std::string error_str;
  llvm::raw_string_ostream ostream{error_str};
  if (llvm::verifyModule(*module_, &ostream)) {
    std::cout << "ERROR found in IR: " << GetIR() << "\nERROR: " << error_str
              << "\n\n";
  }
}
```

Now, what's required is just calling `Verify()` before submitting a module to the optimize layer.